# VLOOKUP with Array Subscript out of range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do what I think should be a simple formula but it's proving difficult. I'm attempting to set a cell equal to a formula via VBA. Here is the code:

```
Dim pivotws_month As Worksheet
Dim departmentArray() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim lrow As Long

lrow = pivotws_month.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim departmentArray(1 to lrow)
departmentArray = pivotws_month.Range("B4:B" & lrow)

i = 4  
For x = 1 to UBound(departmentArray)
   pivotws_month.Cells(i,4).Value = pivotws_month.Cells(i,3) / Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(departmentArray(x), pivotws_month.Range("G4:H" & lrow), 2, False)
i = i + 1
Next x
```

I've debugged my variables and my lrow is correct (297) and the # of items in my array is correct (294). I keep getting a subscript out of range error inside of my For loop and I'm not sure why. Please help, I've been looking around for answer for awhile now.

Comment: A range has two dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a 2D array; supply the rank in all references.

```
...

'this Redim is completely unnecessary
'ReDim departmentArray(1 to lrow)

...

with pivotws_month
    i = 4  
    lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    'create a 2-D array of many 'rows' and one 'column
    departmentArray = .Range("B4:B" & lrow).value
    For x = LBound(departmentArray, 1) to UBound(departmentArray, 1)
       .Cells(i,4).Value = .Cells(i,3) / Application.VLookup(departmentArray(x, 1), .Range("G4:H" & lrow), 2, False)
        i = i + 1
    Next x
end with
```

Loading a variant array from a worksheets range **always** results in a 2-D array. It doesn't matter whether you are loading from a single row or a single columns. It also discards any `Option Base 0` declaration or a ReDim command to a 1-D array prior to the bulk loading code line.

You can test the dimensions of your array after the bulk loading event with the following.

```
debug.print lbound(departmentArray, 1) & ":" & ubound(departmentArray, 1)
debug.print lbound(departmentArray, 2) & ":" & ubound(departmentArray, 2)
```

It may help to think of the first rank (e.g. `ubound(departmentArray, 1)`) as the 'rows' of the array and the second rank (e.g. `ubound(departmentArray, 2)`) as the 'columns' of the array.

There is no error control on that VLOOKUP. A simple no-match #N/A will throw your code into conniptions. The result of an Application.Vlookup can be thrown into a variant and that variant can be tested with IsError. A further test against the variant equaling zero can be used to avoid #DIV/0! results on the division operation in your code.

Comment: Thank you. This worked but I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. I see I was attempting a one dimensional array, was that the issue?

Comment: Yes. Bulk loading an array from the worksheet **always** creates a 2-D array, even if it only many rows in one column or many columns in one row. It even overrides Option Base 0 by creating an array with lbound(s) of 1.